# Производительность Webpack

Tags: reactjs, производительность, webpack

Недавно начал использовать Webpack вместе с ReactJS, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что  время сборки занимает от 150-ти до 200 секунд, Я подозреваю. что это ненормально)) В `/node_modules/` хранится приблизительно 30 плагинов, в babel'e включил  проверку синтаксиса только по "моим" файлам. Подскажите, как можно ускорить сборку или время выполнения в 200 секунд это норма?

В проекте существует уже порядка 50-ти модулей (компоненты, экшены, редюсеры).

P.P.S. Вот  мой вариант конфига, буду благодарен, если поправите!

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./scripts/index",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        include: __dirname + '/scripts',
        loader:
          'babel'
      },
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        include: __dirname + '/styles',
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
      },
      {
        test:/\.styl$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!stylus-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loaders: [
            'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        include: __dirname + '/fonts',
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ]
};
```

Прикладываю Package.json

```
{
  "name": "gps-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "lardi-trans",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^0.7.7",
    "leaflet.icon.glyph": "^0.2.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.1.0",
    "react-color-picker": "^3.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0",
    "react-localization": "0.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.1",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "traverson": "^3.1.3",
    "traverson-hal": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-object-assign": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^1.6.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.2",
    "stylus-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: Вроде не норма, лично я с чем-то дольше нескольких секунд таки не сталкивался

Comment: Скинь свой `webpack.config.js`. У меня сборка проходит примерно за 2-3 секунды. /node_modules/ не должны собираться, они (нужные) попадут в сборку, если они указаны в зависимостях какого либо компонента в твоих сурсах

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев скинул свой вариант!

Comment: Какая-то ерунда. А `package.json`? + Поточнее можно, сколько файлов в папке `/scripts/*.js`

Comment: в папке scripts 62 файла весом 125 кб, пересборка в режиме watch занимает 1,5 - 2 секунды.Дольше всего собирает самый первый bundle.js . Сегодня, например 180 с(при том что  старый bundle не удалялся)

Comment: ерунда какая то :) ну кроме как дебажить, я не знаю вариантов. У вас выводится информация о том, какие модули собираются? Типа такой: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hylxg.png

Comment: Попробую тогда таким образом подебажить, спасибо! В случае чего, буду отписывать результаты!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [HOT MODULE REPLACEMENT](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html). тогда файлы не будут пересобираться заново а только та часть, где произошли изменения

Comment: Просмотрю этот момент в доках и обязательно оставлю фидбек!